# Automatic change of formatting while we answer

Tags: discussion, support, bug, feature-request

Whenever I give answers to the questions, my original format of the answer is not maintained. It is changed to all continuous statements all line by lines. So it becomes very clumsy for the reader, and me too.

How to maintain the answer format?

Comment: I went ahead and modified every answer that needed formatting fixes and removed any unnecessary statements (“Thanks”, “Merry Christmas”, etc).  Please be mindful of the formatting in the future

Comment: **Every** time you go to answer there is a "help" questionmark that gives you hints and tips for formatting. There is even a link to the main help pages for the markdown system that Stack Exchange uses: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXFBm.jpg

Comment: You are also able to see the "source code" for every users answer by clicking the "improve" or "edit" button under it to see how the formatting is achieved. You can then simply cancel the edit. You could also have gone to the [help] where we also hold the markdown formatting guides.

Comment: I'm just guessing from your description, but it sounds like you're putting in paragraph breaks and the result is being displayed as a single large block.  That happens if you use a single "Enter" as a paragraph break.  You need two Enters.  Also, in certain cases, like quoted text, finishing a sentence and following it immediately with an Enter won't be recognized as a new paragraph for text wrapping purposes.  Adding two spaces before the Enter solves most of those.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the exact formatting of your answer is always displayed before you hit the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Post texts are rendered in markdown. By default, whitespaces will be stripped (as happens in HTML, e.g.). You can explicitly format your answer with markdown tags, as well as a limited subset of HTML tags - see [markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) for additional details.